# Failure of Inserting graphic with graphicx in Texstudio

Tags: graphics, installing

I use Texstudio and MikTex 2.9

I guess maybe there is something wrong with the package. The MikTex told me to install the package several times, but it seems that the package has not be installed.

I did put the `.tex` document and the graph in the same folder.

```
the error says:Package pdftex.def Error: File `../figure1.jpg' not found. ...aphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../figure1.jpg}
```

The following is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figure1}
\caption{}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If they are in the same folder, then it should be `./figure1.jpg` or simply `figure1.jpg`

Comment: `.jpg` isn't even needed in general.

Comment: @Bernard I edited my code, but nothingwork:Package pdftex.def Error: File `../figure1.jpg' not found. ...aphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../figure1.jpg}

Comment: Just in case: Is `graphics-def` installed? There were some changes in the architecture of  latex recently.

Comment: @Bernard The MikTex asked me to install a package and I followed it. But it asked me to do the samething several times so I think maybe the installation failed.

Comment: @Bernard I had check the MikTex, it said that it has been installed today.

Comment: miktex solved in URL: </br>
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined </br>

Comment: miktex solved in URL: </br>
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined </br>

Comment: miktex solved in URL: </br>
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined </br>

Comment: miktex solved in URL: </br>
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined </br>

Answer (score 3):

The error message shows that the code you've shared is not the code which produces that message.

In your example, you have

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figure1}
```

but in the code which produces the error, you have

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../figure1.jpg}
```

Those are not the same. The first tells TeX to look in the current directory for `figure1`, an image with one of the known extensions. The second tells TeX to look in the parent of the current directory for `figure1.jpg`. It will not find anything if it is in the current directory instead.

```
./figure1
```

`figure1` in the current directory.

```
figure1
```

`figure1` in the current directory.

```
../figure1
```

`figure1` in the current directory's parent directory i.e. the directory 'above' the current one.

Comment: Sorry but even after I correct that error it does not work...... So could you please tell me what may be wrong with that?

Comment: @Y.X. 'does not work' isn't much help. What happens? Do you get a different error? Which? Does something else happen? Does your computer explode? Presumably you don't get the *same* error once you've corrected it, so you need to now address the *next* one.

Comment: Just the same error, NO change happens.

Comment: @Y.X. If you get exactly the same error after correcting the cause of that error i.e. the error message includes context which is not present in your file at all, delete all generated files and retry. If you still get the same error then either your TeX installation or something else is seriously screwed up. File system corruption, failing hardware, malicious OS, mixed up TeX installation ... You have serious problems if TeX thinks your file includes `../` when it does not. Certainly, those problems are well beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

@cfr is right. There's a world of difference.

I cannot offer an explanation as good as [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr). I, however, can offer what I follow as a practice.

Consider the below picture

[image: ![Folder Structure]

All my `.tex` files are in `.tex folder` and images in `Images Folder`. If I have to link to an image in Images folder I use the command `\graphicspath`.

**I specify the path only *ONCE* (before `\begin{document}`) and use the images by their file name everywhere.**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%Format:- \graphicspath{{path1}{path2}{path3}...}%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{../ImagesFolder/}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{LiLi-USB-Creator}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

No matter how many images I use or how many `.tex` files I create, I stick to the said structure.

**AVOID SPACES IN FILE AND FOLDER NAMES**. LaTeX doesn't like spaces in the files you refer to.

I tried your example in my setup -- with one alteration (`graphicspath`) --  and found **no** errors (none, zero, zilch).

Output:

[image]

**Compiler:** TexLive 2015

**IDE:** TexStudio

**OS:** Ubuntu 15.10

**Edit:**

I have tried this with Windows 8, 8.1 and 10. `\graphicspath` needed no modification.

Thanks [Jan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120477/jan)

Comment: this is also en excellent answer and a lesson worth learning. In my experience, you also have to avoid the usual Windows path separation character, (`\`), which has a special meaning in LaTeX.  Instead, you have to replace all backslashes into normal slashes (`/`).