# MiKTeX graphics version 1.3b bug on Windows 10 (\set@curr@file undefined)

Tags: graphics, miktex, includegraphics

After updating MiKTeX graphics package on 10/5/19 to version 1.3b (packaged on 10/4/2019 8:11:27 PM), I am unable to compile LaTex files that contain `\includegraphics{}`.

My system:
Windows 10  with MiKTeX 2.9.7200

A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{MC_Antenna_Gain}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error report

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/nicrog/Dropbox/T_P_2/Scholar/Grants/Written/EWU_20/Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"))
No file Test.aux.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")))
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.8    \includegraphics{MC_Antenna_Gain}

?
```

I will report this potential bug to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/ as well.

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/131. This should be resolved with today's update.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511060/35864

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As noted in the question, this is an issue in the way MiKTeX has integrated the latest LaTeX kernel change. The `graphics` package has been updated but not the LaTeX kernel, and this leads to the error.

A temporary fix is to add the necessary definitions to your source file: luckily these are small

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\set@curr@file#1{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\@curr@file{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\quote@name#1{"\quote@@name#1\@gobble""}
\def\quote@@name#1"{#1\quote@@name}
\def\unquote@name#1{\quote@@name#1\@gobble"}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Of course, hopefully the kernel will be updated shortly in MiKTeX.

Comment: Updating my MiKTeX install, looks like the fix is already in MiKTeX.

Comment: The issue should hopefully be resolved now https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/131. I couldn't check if the update also triggers a rebuild of the formats due to a slight misconfiguration of my system, but things definitely work fine after rebuilding my formats.

Comment: @JosephWright I tried your code. Problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks Joseph -- This works as advertised.

Comment: I updated miktex but it didn't solve. this comment solves the issue until a new update comes from miktex.

Comment: @Ali did you update as both user and admin and is the mirrir you use up to date?

Comment: @daleif Yes. The package information date for graphics is Sat Oct 5 15:11:12 2019. So I assume this is up-to-date.

Comment: @Ali Try updating the formats (Settings -> Formats -> Build format) both in user and admin mode. This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I tried that, but I got an error.              fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_2019-10-09-073658.out"                                                                This error occurs in Admin- and User-Mode. What else can I do?

Comment: @RolandDeschain That's a MLTeX issue: please post a separate question

Comment: Same problem using BasicTeX on macOS, the proposed temporary fix works. Does anyone know where BasicTeX issues can be reported (is it really just [this form or via email](http://www.tug.org/mactex/support/emailform/index.html))?

Comment: On TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) same error, when i compiled it with lualatex (LuaTeX version 1.10.0). Fix is working.

Comment: @cbrnr BasicTeX is a simple TeX Live wrapper, and the issue is fixed there: try updating your sytem

Comment: @maphy-psd Updating your TeX system should sort the issue; you may need to force a format-rebuild

Comment: I just updated right now, on a machine that did not have this problem, and includegraphics is now broken on this machine.

Comment: @joseph-wright after `fmtutil-sys --all` everything works..thank you!

Comment: @maphy-psd Where would I type fmtutil-sys --all to se if this works for me?

Comment: @JosephWright thanks, this worked. @ColinMcLarty you need to type `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` in a terminal (e.g. the Terminal.app on macOS).

Comment: @cbmr My Windows 10 machine says "'fmtutil-sys --all' is not recognized as an internal or external command." Adding sudo gets the same result

Comment: In my Win10 x64 machine I had to uninstall and reinstall MiKTeX. Then, rebuild formats (both user and admin mode) for "latex2e" and "pdfLaTeX" made the trick. (I tried to rebuild without uninstalling but it didn't work).

Answer (score 16):

**The core of this issue has been fixed (on 2019-10-06) in MikTeX**, but since the situation involves formats and is overall a bit tricky I wrote up a guide at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/131 explaining (roughly) what is happening here and what you can do if you are still suffering from this issue. This is copied pretty much verbatim from over there.

OK, this turned out to be quite a tricky issue, since there are several things at play here.

## The heart of the issue: Incompatible packages

The core of the issue was as follows. The LaTeX development team released an [update of the LaTeX kernel (LaTeX base in `ltxbase`) along with several core packages (e.g. `graphics`, `graphicx`, `amsmath`)](https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/2019-October/012996.html). The updated core packages are intended to work with the updated LaTeX kernel and some need the correct version to function properly. Among these core packages was `graphics`/`graphicx`.

The packages and the kernel were uploaded to CTAN at almost the same time and arrived in TeX live with [the same sweep of updates](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-October/011010.html). Due to unfortunate timing, only `graphics` was updated in MikTeX leaving the LaTeX kernel on an older version. Using the `graphicx` package with the older kernel causes the error messages described in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/132, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/133 and here (as well as linked questions and duplicates).

The core issue of the MikTeX package server distributing incompatible packages was fixed swiftly the next day on 2019-10-06 (UTC). Since then the server has distributed the newest LaTeX base package (2019-10-01) that matches `graphics`.

## The LaTeX kernel is special

Usually when a package is updated it is enough to renew the file name database to tell TeX about the addition or removal of files. This happens automatically when the MikTeX Console is used to update or install packages (same for TeX live's `tlmgr` and friends) so the average user will not have to worry about that.

But the LaTeX kernel is special. It defines a *TeX format* and is directly baked into the executable so that all LaTeX commands are available from the start without loading any packages (the LaTeX commands can be used without any `\usepackage` directly from the start). This means that it is not enough to renew the file name database when the kernel was updated: the formats also need to be regenerated and baked into the executables. Again this should happen automatically when the MikTeX Console is used to update the LaTeX kernel package.

## OK, so what can I do?

### Update in Admin and User mode

First of all you need to make sure that your MikTeX system is fully up to date. Run an update (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/35864). If you have a multi-user MikTeX make sure to run the Update in User *and* Admin mode.

Double check that `lxtbase` is up to date by going to the *Packages* tab in the MikTeX Console and searching for `ltxbase`. The install date should be 2019-10-06 or later and the packaged date 2019-10-05. If you have a multi-user MikTeX install, the package may only be installed in one of the two modes. You do not have to click install in the other mode, you just have to make sure that it is up to date *when* it is installed.

In an ideal world that should be it. The formats should automatically be generated as needed during the update and things should work.

Small aside: The admin–user distinction is a common source of problems in MikTeX. The updater will always only update the packages installed with its permission level. If you have a multi-user installation and installed packages with User-level as well as Admin-level permissions, packages may get out of sync if you only update with one permission level. Whenever you encounter an update-related issue always make sure to update your system in Admin and User mode, often that makes issues go away. (Of course this only applies to multi-user MikTeX installs.)

### Check your format

You can check your LaTeX format by running a simple LaTeX document like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

Open the resulting `.log` file and check out the first few lines

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.12)  12 OCT 2019 11:42
entering extended mode
**./formatdate.tex
(formatdate.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
```

The important bit is the

```
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
```

the date should be `2019-10-01` or above.

The date in the `preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.12` in the very first line should show a date after 2019-10-06.

You can use the command

```
kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt
```

from the terminal to find out where your format resides. The folder may give you a hint whether or not you are dealing with a User- or Admin-controlled format. This is important for the next step. If it is `C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/data/le/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt` the format is user-controlled, if the format resides in `C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/data/le/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt` we're talking about an Admin-controlled format. If the file path looks nothing like the two examples it may well be that you have a spurious format spooking around somewhere.

### Recreate the formats

If your formats are not new enough, MikTeX either did not recreate the format during the update or it did recreate the formats, but still picks up older versions of the formats.

You can rebuild the TeX formats as described in [MiKTeX: Error After Update: "Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500534/35864). You will need to rebuild all the formats you want to use (probably at least `pdflatex`, `latex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`). It may be possible to simply select all formats and rebuild them, but some formats may produce errors on rebuild. In that case you may need to hand-pick the formats you need.

Again if you have a multi-user installation there might be a need to do this in Admin and User mode. Generally I recommend to rebuild the formats in Admin mode first (if you have Admin rights that is) and only then if still necessary in User mode.

In case the relevant formats create error you can not resolve or understand on rebuilding, ask a question on your favourite TeX forum and give enough details so people understand what you did.

If you rebuilt the formats and still MikTeX doesn't pick up the correct formats, your MikTeX might be misconfigured. This is then going to be a specific issue that can only be diagnosed with more detailed information about your system. Again it might be better to ask a question with as much detail as possible on your favourite TeX forum.

## Last comments

The fix from [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511144/35864) is intended to be a *temporary* workaround. It should not be needed any more since the correct kernel version is now available in MikTeX. Please don't use this workaround any more. Instead make sure that you format gets updated correctly.

If you want to know more about TeX *formats*, LaTeX etc., have a look at http://www.tug.org/levels.html and [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/35864). Overleaf has a nice article on formats at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/The_two_modes_of_TeX_engines:_INI_mode_and_production_mode.

Incidentally new installers and the like will probably not help here, since this is purely an issue related to things that happen after installation. Indeed it may not even help to remove MikTeX and install a new version if problematic files remain in directories not controlled by MikTeX. It is therefore important to try and understand where the problem comes from before going on an uninstall-reinstall spree.

---

## MacTeX

As it turns out there is a related issue in MacTeX (which is based on TeX live and not on MikTeX): [\includegraphics broken on MacTeX 2019?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511615/35864). Updates in MacTeX don't trigger format rebuilding, which means that even though all packages are up to date one might be stuck with an older LaTeX format. In that case

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

should help fix the issue.

A more detailed discussion about why that is necessary is at https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-October/044119.html.

Answer (score 3):

Using use package `graphicx` (which call `graphics`) instead of `graphics` works fine with recent MikTeX (just upgraded):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % <--- in real document remove option "demo"

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{MC_Antenna_Gain}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko -- I had already tried that without the [demo] when I posted this.  However, I can confirm that adding the [demo] does work, but the black box is not really useful in the end.

Comment: @uRog, option `demo` I use since I haven't your picture. In real document, you  must remove this option (as I noted in code example) and your image should show up.

Comment: @Zarko  This works for me if I use demo and get a black box. If I do not use demo it gives the same error message as the graphics package.  I did replace your graphic MC_Antenna_Gain with one of my own.

Comment: These two steps from the above comments solved my issue: 1. "If you have a multi-user installation and installed packages with User-level as well as Admin-level permissions, packages may get out of sync if you only update with one permission level." 2. You will need to rebuild all the formats you want to use (probably at least pdflatex, latex, xelatex, lualatex)." Apply step 2 in BOTH user level and admin level.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. I posted a link to your answer in another page!