# MikTeX issue after update: initexmf.exe

Tags: errors, miktex, update

I have the same problem as stated in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined). After updating MikTeX I am unable to compile LaTex files that contain `\includegraphics{}`. The temporary fix from Joseph Wright solved the problem. My MiKTeX-distribution is up-tp-date.

A comment from COOLSerdash suggested to update the formats from MiKTeX

`Settings -> Formats -> Build format`

both in user and admin mode. But I get an error:

[image]

```
fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_2019-10-09-073658.out"
```

What else can I do to solve the problem?

---

**Solution**

My problem was, that I selected all formats and rebuild all of them. After I just selected `pdflatex` and rebuild the format this fixed the problem. I run the update in User and Admin mode.

Now I get the correct entry: `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>`.

Comment: Run the update in user and admin mode, if the problem persist, open an issue at the miktex issue tracker and don't forget to mention what the output file in the error message says.

Comment: I had the same problem rebuilding the formats. It was solved by turning off my anti-virus software. I suppose my anti-virus software is too aggressive on MiKTeX (I turn it off whenever I update packages).