# \includegraphics broken on MacTeX 2019?

Tags: graphics, mactex, includegraphics

On MacTeX 2019, I get the following error when using `\includegraphics`:

```
./test.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.5 \includegraphics{ddg.png}
```

The following MWE does not work (yes, `ddg.png` is there):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{ddg.png}
\end{document}
```

This happens both with `XeLaTeX` and `pdfLaTeX`.
Anybody got any ideas or even the same issue?

Sadly, I can't track down what I did to cause this bug, it presumably happened when auto-updating packages with `tlmgr`.
I know it worked fine like a couple days ago.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined/511144?noredirect=1#comment1293602_511144?

Comment: with texlive/mactex that error should not be possible, latex/base and latex/graphics should both have updated together.

Comment: @JosephWright wow, thanks! I had actually seen that post but immediately discarded it because it said it was a `miktex` specific bug! The fix worked flawlessly, though.

@DavidCarlisle: How can I check whether that was the case or not, how can I update them manually? Because apparently it was the same error (or at least, it had the same fix).

Comment: the fix in Joseh's answer was just a temp workaround for a day or so until the miktex distribution was fixed. As the texlive (mactex)  distribution didn't have that problem you have a local issue so it would be better to fix it than use the workaround (as otherwise it might never get fixed). firstly what date does latex give when it starts up? it should be `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` if it is a 2018 date try `fmtutil-sys --all` to rebuild the formats

Comment: It was indeed a 2018 date, problem solved, thank you so much!

(I don't exactly understand *what* was from 2018 though; I assumed to be working with a fresh install of MacTeX 2019).

Comment: Got the same error. @DavidCarlisle suggestion with `fmtutil-sys --all` fixed the issue.

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski after the mactex wrapper around tlmgr downloaded the new 2019 sources it was _supposed_ to have run fmtutil-sys --all and remade the formats but apparently it didn't so you had new run time packages loading into an old format which is an untested (and sometimes not working) situation. That isn't supposed to happen so it may be worth asking on a mactex support list, but may be hard to reproduce once the formats have been updated.