# \includegraphics not working in Plain TeX after update

Tags: graphics, plain-tex, includegraphics

I have been using `\includegraphics` with plain TeX without problems until yesterday, when I updated TeXLive and wrote (minimal)

```
\input miniltx
\input graphicx.sty
\includegraphics{espec.png}
\bye
```

The compilation showed

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...

\Gin@ii ...eys {Gin}{#1}\Gin@esetsize \the \toks@ 
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.6 \includegraphics{espec.png}
```

and stopped.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The fix proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511144/134574) might work for you...

Comment: Thanks, Phelype. I use plain.tex, so I do not know how to adapt the solution proposed for Latex

Comment: The fix is likely to go into the next `graphics` release, and should cover plain

Answer (score 6):

This is the same fix proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511144/134574), adapted to Plain. The differences are that `\makeatletter` becomes `` \catcode`\@=11 ``, `\m@ne` becomes `-1`. Also `graphicx.sty` expects `@` to be catcode 11, so we move the `` \catcode`\@=12 `` (`\makeatother`) after loading it:

```latex
\input miniltx
% Start fix
\catcode`\@=11
\def\set@curr@file#1{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar=-1
    \xdef\@curr@file{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\quote@name#1{"\quote@@name#1\@gobble""}
\def\quote@@name#1"{#1\quote@@name}
\def\unquote@name#1{\quote@@name#1\@gobble"}
% End fix
\input graphicx.sty
\catcode`\@=12
\includegraphics{example-image}
\bye
```

Comment: It works! Wonderful! Thanks a lot