# Having problem with figures since last update

Tags: floats, errors, miktex, includegraphics

I have updated the packages of miktex and now when I compile my file, the figures \includegraphics are not compiled and show only as a line of the figure name.
I reinstalled both miktex and the texniccenter but no solution.
Is it a bug? Any one please has a similar experience or an advice?

Comment: You must rebuild format files in both admin and user modes too. Open MiKTeX Console, then `Settings -> Formats`. Select all necessary formats and click `Build format`. I failed many times before I turned off my anti-virus software, then the rebuild was successful. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511138/164314

Comment: Dear Ruixi Zhang, thank you very much for your kind reply. I tried to follow your advice and I had error relating to "initexmf.exe" with some formats with and without my antivirus software (even in safe mod). Even though, there are some formats were rebuilt and some installation were occurred. I visited the topic you have mentioned and added the lines suggested in the first answer which solved my problem. Unfortunately, I cannot explain the logic behind that solution but really worked fine with me. Many thanks!!

Comment: Read this page and its answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512092/miktex-cannot-fix-the-includegraphics-error-by-rebuilding-formats-format-stil/512530#512530