# MikTeX: Cannot fix the \includegraphics error by rebuilding formats (format still says LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>)

Tags: miktex, latex-base, format-files

I was hit by the recent problems with `\includegraphics` and followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512049/130867 in order to fix it. However, rebuilding my formats in the MikTeX console does not help. Building one at a time doesn't return an error but just does nothing, while building `tex`, `latex`, `pdftex` and `pdflatex` at the same time gives the error:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2019-10-13 18:26:12
MiKTeX: 2.9.7200
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 18362
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2019-10-13 18:23:12
LastUpdateAdmin: 2019-10-13 16:59:48
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
AdminMode: yes
Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: D:\Nuttig\vierkantLaTeX\texmf
Root2: D:\Nuttig\hextex\texmf
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: 

ERROR DETAILS
Program: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console_admin.exe
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\Console\Qt\mainwindow.cpp:980
Error: The MiKTeX configuration utility failed for some reason. The process output has been saved to a file.
Details: 
  fileName: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe
  exitCode: 1
  savedOutput: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_2019-10-13-182542.out
```

I think the problem is the `\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe` slashing swapping, but I have no idea why the slashes are that way or how to fix it.

Is there a way to just build the formats from console commands without having to use the MikTeX console? Would that fix this case?

Thank you very much in advance.

**Update:** After retesting one-by-one, the tex (plain TeX) format gave the same error upon building. The error log file it refers to just says:

```
  Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

  The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log
```

**Update 2:** initexmf_admin.log has a log from a long time, only including today's things gives (a lot of repetition, I re-tried several times):

```
2019-10-13 16:52:42,347+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:52:42,347+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:52:42,348+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:52:42,351+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:52:42,441+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:52:45,469+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:52:48,644+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:52:48,644+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:52:48,644+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:52:48,645+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:52:48,706+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:52:51,335+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:52:53,032+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:52:53,032+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:52:53,032+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:52:53,033+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:52:53,096+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:52:55,749+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:52:57,645+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:52:57,645+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:52:57,645+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:52:57,646+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:52:57,707+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:00,315+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:02,705+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:02,706+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:02,706+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:02,707+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:02,766+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:05,400+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:07,322+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:07,322+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:07,322+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:07,323+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:07,387+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:09,963+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:22,374+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:22,374+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:22,374+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:22,375+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:22,436+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:25,039+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:28,066+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:28,066+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:28,066+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:28,067+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:28,129+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:30,656+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:33,046+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:33,046+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:33,046+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:33,047+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:33,107+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:35,641+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:53:37,502+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7106 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:53:37,502+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:53:37,502+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:53:37,503+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:53:37,562+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:53:40,146+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:59:49,034+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:59:49,034+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:59:49,034+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 16:59:49,035+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:59:49,115+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 16:59:51,848+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:59:52,659+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:59:52,659+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:59:52,659+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --update-fndb --admin --disable-installer --verbose
2019-10-13 16:59:52,698+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-10-13 16:59:52,714+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (D:/Nuttig/vierkantLaTeX/texmf)...
2019-10-13 16:59:52,972+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (D:/Nuttig/hextex/texmf)...
2019-10-13 16:59:52,976+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2019-10-13 16:59:56,533+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 16:59:56,771+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 16:59:56,771+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 16:59:56,772+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --force --mklinks --admin --disable-installer --verbose
2019-10-13 16:59:56,772+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 16:59:59,905+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 17:00:09,278+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 17:00:09,279+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 17:00:09,279+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --mkmaps --mklangs --admin --disable-installer --verbose
2019-10-13 17:00:09,279+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2019-10-13 17:00:09,346+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --verbose --admin --disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 17:00:11,792+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 17:00:12,044+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 17:00:12,044+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 17:00:12,044+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --register-shell-file-types --admin --disable-installer --verbose
2019-10-13 17:00:12,048+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .asy
2019-10-13 17:00:12,049+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .bib
2019-10-13 17:00:12,050+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .cls
2019-10-13 17:00:12,052+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .dtx
2019-10-13 17:00:12,053+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .dvi
2019-10-13 17:00:12,055+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .ltx
2019-10-13 17:00:12,056+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .pdf
2019-10-13 17:00:12,058+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .sty
2019-10-13 17:00:12,059+0200 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .tex
2019-10-13 17:00:12,095+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 17:02:16,768+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 17:02:16,768+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 17:02:16,768+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 17:02:16,769+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 17:02:16,839+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 17:02:19,103+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:00:28,196+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:00:28,197+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:00:28,197+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=pdflatex
2019-10-13 18:00:28,201+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:00:32,286+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:00:48,730+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:00:48,730+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:00:48,730+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=latex-dev
2019-10-13 18:00:48,735+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=latex-dev --no-dump latex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:00:55,987+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:00:55,987+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:00:55,987+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --mkmaps --mklinks
2019-10-13 18:00:55,989+0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating links in target directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64...
2019-10-13 18:00:56,052+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:00:58,505+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:01:01,648+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:04:51,423+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:04:51,423+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:04:51,423+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=pdflatex
2019-10-13 18:04:51,427+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:04:54,670+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:06:25,417+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:06:25,417+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:06:25,417+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=latex
2019-10-13 18:06:25,421+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=latex --no-dump latex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:06:28,719+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:10:54,049+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:10:54,050+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:10:54,050+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=etex
2019-10-13 18:10:54,054+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=etex --no-dump etex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:10:55,310+0200 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-10-13-181055.out'
2019-10-13 18:10:55,311+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-10-13 18:10:55,311+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2019-10-13 18:10:55,311+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2019-10-13 18:10:55,311+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
2019-10-13 18:11:17,632+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:11:17,633+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:11:17,633+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=lualatex
2019-10-13 18:11:17,637+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=luatex --dest-name=lualatex --no-dump lualatex.ini --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:11:19,188+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:16:24,037+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:16:24,038+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:16:24,038+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=pdflatex
2019-10-13 18:16:24,043+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:16:28,040+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:18:40,881+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:18:40,881+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:18:40,881+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=xelatex
2019-10-13 18:18:40,886+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=xetex --dest-name=xelatex --no-dump xelatex.ini --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:18:43,372+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:20:53,939+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:20:53,939+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:20:53,939+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=pdflatex
2019-10-13 18:20:53,943+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:20:57,102+0200 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-10-13 18:25:35,820+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:25:35,821+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:25:35,821+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=tex
2019-10-13 18:25:35,829+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=tex --dest-name=tex --no-dump tex.ini --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:25:42,672+0200 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-10-13-182542.out'
2019-10-13 18:25:42,673+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-10-13 18:25:42,673+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2019-10-13 18:25:42,673+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2019-10-13 18:25:42,673+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
2019-10-13 18:36:40,673+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:36:40,673+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:36:40,673+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=tex
2019-10-13 18:36:40,677+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=tex --dest-name=tex --no-dump tex.ini --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:36:41,427+0200 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-10-13-183641.out'
2019-10-13 18:36:41,427+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-10-13 18:36:41,427+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2019-10-13 18:36:41,427+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2019-10-13 18:36:41,427+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
2019-10-13 18:39:44,170+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7207 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
2019-10-13 18:39:44,170+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2019-10-13 18:39:44,170+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --admin --dump=tex
2019-10-13 18:39:44,174+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=tex --dest-name=tex --no-dump tex.ini --admin --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-10-13 18:39:44,916+0200 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-10-13-183944.out'
2019-10-13 18:39:44,917+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-10-13 18:39:44,917+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2019-10-13 18:39:44,917+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2019-10-13 18:39:44,917+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
```

Comment: What do you get when you run on a command line `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`?

Comment: what information is in the log file you reference C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get
C:/Users/pepdm/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/data/le/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will update it to the post.

Comment: You have a user format, so try to rebuild it with the miktex console in user mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That seems to have fixed it, thank you very much. I'm pretty sure I have only ever used admin mode (PC only has one user which is the admin) so I'm not sure how the user part appeared.

Comment: Under my installation path `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` I have both `miktex-console.exe` and `miktex-console_admin.exe`. You should have these two executables too.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answer in this link [MiKTeX graphics version 1.3b bug on Windows 10 (\set@curr@file undefined)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined) 
Note the meant answer is the answer which starts with

> The core of this issue has been fixed (on 2019-10-06) in MikTeX,...

*By moewe*

Stick to these three steps from the above answer link:

1. "If you have a multi-user installation and installed packages with User-level as well as Admin-level permissions, packages may get out of sync if you only update with one permission level."
2. "You will need to rebuild all the formats you want to use (probably at least `pdflatex`, `latex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`)."
3. Apply step 2 in **BOTH** user level and admin level.

This solved my issue completely. (Just in case, disable your antivirus during format update)