# Error \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I was working on a document and had a problem with the compilation of it. I updated the MiKTeX library and after that, all the pictures that I include in my document do not work anymore. I'm using `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` and also included `pdftex` and other options.

All the pictures send an error of undefined control sequence. What should I do? I'm already changing my TeX distribution to TeX Live to find the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511138/134574? You need to have MiKTeX rebuild the LaTeX format.

Comment: Thanks, Phelype, it was really useful information. Regards.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Please tell if that solved the problem, then we can mark as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm trying to solve it, but I think is the same problem in the link