# Problem with the include graphics command

Tags: graphics

I have a problem with the include graphics command. I have my pictures saved in the same folder with the main document but when I use for example \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{K5} I get the File not found error. What I really don't understand is that I have compiled this file in the past and I had no problems. Also when the cursor is on the name of the image I can see the image so it seems that it can actually find the image but it doesnt appear in the pdf. I hadn't opend the file for a couple of months and I had some new packages and updates installed in MikTeX a few days ago. Could some of them create such a problem? Any suggestions how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined perhaps

Comment: Yes I have the same problem! Thank you that really helped!!