# After MikTex package update -> No float figures

Tags: lyx, miktex

I really need some help here. So, I am using Lyx to write my thesis right now. I updated the packages over the MikTex Console and since then, NO float figures are shown in the output. Since I have many float objects, the log file is huge... I try to copy some of it in here:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unquote@name 

l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: File `1D__Doktorarbeit__Doktorarbeit_Bilder__Zitat_04___seen_fro
m_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.254 ...om_Mars_rover_PIA17936_02_bearbeitet.jpg}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmss/m/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 257.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmss/m/it' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 257.
[5

] [6

] [7

] [8

] [9] [10

] (Thesis_01.toc [1



] [2] [3]
Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 138
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 113
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 146
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 123
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 150
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 125
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 151
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 127
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 156
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 131
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 157
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 146
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.5877pt too wide) detected at line 158
 []\T1/lmss/bx/n/12 147
 []

)
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `Thesis_01.toc'.

[4]
chapter 1.

Class scrbook Warning: \float@addtolists detected!
(scrbook)              Implementation of \float@addtolist became
(scrbook)              deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and
(scrbook)              has been replaced by several more flexible
(scrbook)              features of package `tocbasic`.
(scrbook)              Since Version 3.12 support for deprecated
(scrbook)              \float@addtolist interface has been
(scrbook)              restricted to only some of the KOMA-Script
(scrbook)              features and been removed from others.
(scrbook)              Loading of package `scrhack' may help to
(scrbook)              avoid this warning, if you are using a
(scrbook)              a package that still implements the
(scrbook)              deprecated \float@addtolist interface .
```

If I could undo the MikTex package update, I would! So if someone knows how that would be great! I am really frustrated as I am not so in to this topic and I need to end my thesis! So, please help me out here and be patient with me. Thanks!!

Comment: Possibly another duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511138/134574. You need to update both the `graphics` package (which you already did) and `ltxbase`, and you need to make sure that MiKTeX rebuilt the LaTeX format (see moewe's answer).

Comment: Ahhh perfect! I just saw the solution as well! But thanks for your fast help!! I had some trouble updating it, but no it is working! :)