# Undefined control sequence error using images through Pandoc

Tags: graphics, pandoc

I am trying to insert an image in my pandoc document for the first time and have this code:

```
![Graph](3c.jpg)
```

When I run this through pandoc I get the error

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
\grffile@org@Ginclude@graphics ... \set@curr@file
                                              {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.215 ...bb895ffd5f684410677618f069f8ceb54436.jpg}
```

I have tried adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` to my header-includes but this makes no difference. What am I missing here?

Comment: Exactly which latex installatiton do you use? We have seen this error a lot lately caused by users incorrectly updating their LaTeX installations (only packages were updated, the kernel and its format was not updated).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512049/3929