# ERROR Undefined control sequence `\includegraphics`

Tags: graphics, tex-core

My question has been asked severals times on the forum but nothing works for me.

I would like to insert a picture. Here's a simple example that should work but which doesn't.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{dessin} 

\end{document}
```

I receive those error messages

[image]

Does someone have an idea?

I must add that a `dessin.jpg` file is present in the same directory as my `.tex` file. Finally, this topic [MiKTeX graphics version 1.3b bug on Windows 10 (\set@curr@file undefined)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined) doesn't work for me either

Comment: Je tiens à préciser qu'une image dessin.jpg se trouve dans le même répertoire que mon document .tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We use English, so you should translate your question accordingly. Although, from the error message this is probably due to an issue introduced in MiKTeX which is now solved. I marked the duplicate question.

Comment: It's a dupe: almost certainly you have the infamous issue that MiKTeX needs updating as 'user' and 'admin'

Comment: Thank you for your response Joseph
So you're telling me that I can't do anything. I just have to wait for MiKTeX to update ?

Comment: @AndreiiHtn No! Try running the Update Wizard in both _user_ and _admin_ modes, then manually go to the Settings - Formats tab in the management console and re-create the pdfLaTex format.

Comment: I updated MiKTeX using the MiKTeX Consol and it works fine now. Thank you for your help guys