Redefine \marginpar with \renewcommand gives infinite loop
I want to redefine \marginpar to include a counter for how much space in the margin is already used. This counter is later used in \marginbarrier (with an argument of how much space to reserve in the margin)  to force a \newpage to cause output when the margin is full. The code works as long as the command is not called \marginpar (e.g. \marginpage as commented out), but my intention is to use it as a drop in replacement in marginfix and sidenotes packages.
If I use \renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]% I get no response and I guess I have an infinite loop. I looked at another similar question and tried the advice given there with \let and then get the error Undefined control sequence. ONE \maintext note1\marginpar{1 \filltext} which I do not understand as all these commands are defined.
I am new to such use of Latex and assume that I miss something basic or made a stupid mistake. Help is greatly appreciated!
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum 
    sapientem ne neque dolor erat,eros solet invidunt 
     lobortis est Utinam, enim commune corrumpit 
     Aenean erat tellus. Metus sed amet dolore justo, gubergren sed.
    END OF MARGIN TEXT}

\newcommand{\maintext}{\lipsum[75]}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\newlength{\margintotal}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\global\margintotal=0pt}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}

\newcommand{\marginparold}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}

%\let\marginarold\marginpar 

%\newcommand{\marginpage}[1]{
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]%
    {%
    \savebox{\marginbox}
        {\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{#1}}%
        \global\advance\margintotal by \dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
        \marginparold{\box\marginbox}%  this puts it into the margin
    }

\newcommand{\marginbarrier}[1]%
    {%
        \ifdim 0pt >\dimexpr \textheight - #1 - \margintotal - \ht\marginbox\relax 
              \newpage
        \fi
    }

\begin{document} 
    ONE \maintext  note1\marginpar{1 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

    \marginbarrier{190pt} 
    TWO \maintext  note2\marginpar{2 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

    \marginbarrier{380pt} % next paragraph has two notes!
    THREE \maintext note3\marginpar{3 \filltext} the paragraph should be broken and 
        the last line with the margin note  
        on the next page. note4\marginpar{4 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

\end{document}


note the form of the undefined command error you show is not what tex outputs, you have omitted the main part which shows which command is undefined.

I copied what texstudio showed; if I had looked at the log file, I could have seen that the end of the line was \marginpaold. is what is printed at the end of the line the command that caused the error? I try to learn...

texstudio completely destroys the meaning of error messages in its completely useless summary It has been reported again and again but still it never changes, I have never used texstudio but I guessed you were using it just by your confusion as you are the 1000000th person to be confused by its error "summary" https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515325/undefined-control-sequence-includegraphics-after-texstudio-update#comment1303046_515327

yes the help text of undefined command error is (if you type h to the prompt) The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined

I am willing to change editors. what would you recommend? texmaker, texwork, vscode? what else?

Don't ask me: I have used emacs more or less every day since 1987, you won't get an objective comparison. By all accounts texstudio is a good editor with tex-specific features, it's just that its summary of error messages is not at all helpful. We do have specific questions on this site listing editors eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85249/1090

Texstudio hos have a pane with the actual log in it. Use that when you want to report it to others. Another problem with the editor log parser is if you ask latex to report the filename in front of the error, then the error parsing breaks

currently you have explicitly defined an infinitite loop, \marginpar expands to \marginparold which expands to \marginpar so loops forever.
If you uncomment the \let so your document looks like
%\newcommand{\marginparold}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}

\let\marginarold\marginpar 

then you get the error
! Undefined control sequence.
\marginpar ...\dp \marginbox \relax \marginparold 
                                                  {\box \marginbox }
l.40 ...NE \maintext  note1\marginpar{1 \filltext}
                                                   and the rest of the para!
? 

as \marginparold is not defined (the \let has a typo and a missing p)
The presumably intended \let was
\let\marginparold\marginpar 

which more or less works in this case but using \let on latex defined commands isn't in general safe as it only does a "shallow copy"  of the top level of the command definition. Better to use \NewCommandCopy
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum 
    sapientem ne neque dolor erat,eros solet invidunt 
     lobortis est Utinam, enim commune corrumpit 
     Aenean erat tellus. Metus sed amet dolore justo, gubergren sed.
    END OF MARGIN TEXT}

\newcommand{\maintext}{\lipsum[75]}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\newlength{\margintotal}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\global\margintotal=0pt}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}

%\newcommand{\marginparold}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}

\NewCommandCopy\marginparold\marginpar 

%\newcommand{\marginpage}[1]{
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]%
    {%
    \savebox{\marginbox}
        {\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{#1}}%
        \global\advance\margintotal by \dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
        \marginparold{\box\marginbox}%  this puts it into the margin
    }

\newcommand{\marginbarrier}[1]%
    {%
        \ifdim 0pt >\dimexpr \textheight - #1 - \margintotal - \ht\marginbox\relax 
              \newpage
        \fi
    }

\begin{document} 
    ONE \maintext  note1\marginpar{1 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

    \marginbarrier{190pt} 
    TWO \maintext  note2\marginpar{2 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

    \marginbarrier{380pt} % next paragraph has two notes!
    THREE \maintext note3\marginpar{3 \filltext} the paragraph should be broken and 
        the last line with the margin note  
        on the next page. note4\marginpar{4 \filltext} and the rest of the para!

\end{document}


Thank you for the correction. Now it works. For beginners, the question where to look in code, which is partially understood, is difficult and my guesses were misleading. I had wrongly assumed that \NewCommandCopy is tied to explSyntax. Why does the \newcommand xold  x not work? I saw it in several code pieces I looked at?

@user855443 your newcommand version in the question is an explicit loop (there is no other way of programming a loop in tex, there is no loop primitive, all loops are defined by calling a macro which ultimately calls itself again). So it works, it just doesn't do what you intended.
