# Question with "! Undefined control sequence" using TeX

Tags: undefined

I have some problem using an old file, which worked totally fine previously. But now there is some problem regarding the

> ​ ! Undefined control sequence

here.

The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{beamer}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 % this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 % (ERT) argument for the TOC
 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\definecolor{mycolumbia}{RGB}{117, 178, 221}
\definecolor{mycolumbia2}{RGB}{217, 241, 247}
\definecolor{mycolumbia3}{RGB}{6, 42, 120}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=default,fg=white,bg=mycolumbia}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=default,fg=mycolumbia3,bg=mycolumbia2}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=default,fg=white,bg=mycolumbia}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=default,fg=white,bg=mycolumbia2}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=mycolumbia3,bg=white!95!black}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=mycolumbia3}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=mycolumbia3}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title[Lecture \#18]{Nonlinear Regression Models}
\author{ECO}
\institute{123}
\date{\today}
\makebeamertitle

%======================================================================================================================
%Announcements

%\begin{frame}{Announcements}
%\begin{itemize}
%\item Assignment \#3 is due today
%\medskip
%\item Assignment \#4 has been posted and is due on Tuesday, November 20
%\end{itemize}
%\end{frame}
```

And the result is

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfauthor' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 46.

[1{C:/Users/keicz/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\softwares\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(D:\softwares\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd)
(D:\softwares\MiKTeX\tex/latex/esint\uesint.fd)
(D:\softwares\MiKTeX\tex/latex/jknappen\ursfs.fd)
(D:\softwares\MiKTeX\tex/latex/sansmathaccent\ot1mathkerncmss.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.74 \end{frame}

?
```

I tried many ways but it just does not work.

Comment: You need to update MikTeX. There was a bug which broke graphics inclusion.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined?r=SearchResults&s=1|75.6470

Comment: Missing `\end{document}` at the end of the file