# After MikTeX and TeXstudio upgrade I'm getting error at includegraphics

Tags: errors

since my stuff were outdated I decided this afternoon to update everything to a newer version but now my .tex source do not compile anymore. Specifically I started getting errors on every \includegraphics I have in the source file and moreover it looks like the compiler can't find the images anymore since for each one of them it says "File /Images/[name of the image] not found". The folder structure is this one:

- Tex
- [Name of the PDF]
- .tex source files
- Images

  - Image 1
  - Image 2

A typical (they're are all like this one) part of code giving me errors looks like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/Ampere}
    \caption{Definizione di Ampère}
    \label{fig:Ampere}
\end{figure}
```

I already included graphicx to my document so that is not the problem here. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small, yet complete, code reproducing you problem? B. t. w., what its  your distribution, and which version of the `graphicx` package? There has been problems recently withe latest latex  update.

Comment: did you update as admin and as user?

Comment: It could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511138/35864, but It would really help us if you could show us all relevant error message from a small minimal example document.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks. That fixed it for me!