# Reinstalled MikTex, now nothing works

Tags: miktex, texstudio

Like the title says, I reinstalled MikTex and now I'm getting errors left and right.

Take this simple script (filename = main.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }

\begin{document}
    The universe is immense and it seems to be homogeneous, 
    in a large scale, everywhere we look at.

    \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

    There's a picture of a galaxy above
\end{document}
```

This is the structure revealed by `tree /F`:

```
C:.
│   main.tex
│
└───Figures
        controlcircuit.png
```

Spits out the errors

```
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
Undefined control sequence. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
File `controlcircuit' not found. \includegraphics{controlcircuit}
```

How can Texstudio be repaired?

**EDIT: This is the complete log**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2019.11.4)  19 NOV 2019 14:44
entering extended mode
**./main.tex
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/07/20 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
No file main.aux.
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unquote@name 

l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: File `controlcircuit' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9     \includegraphics{controlcircuit}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1

] (main.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 577 strings out of 492896
 7060 string characters out of 3133505
 65257 words of memory out of 3000000
 4552 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,23p,212b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 720 bytes).
```

Comment: show the real error messages from the log-file, not the truncated stuff from texstudio.

Comment: check out the edit!

Comment: Your miktex is not up-to-date. Run in the console the update manager in user and admin mode. Go also to the package manager (user and admin mode too), update the package database and check if there are new, not installed packages that you perhaps need.

Comment: Have a look at the guide in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511138/35864. You need to update your MikTeX completely and thoroughly.