# ! Undefined control sequence. \Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\

Tags: graphics, pdftex, graphs, include, includegraphics

what mean this error and what should i do to solve it please help me 
(! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file
{#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {...)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512049/134144

Comment: merciii beaucoup